# How can I set HISTSIZE for all users?

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, history

How can I set HISTSIZE for *all* users on Ubuntu 10.04?

I've tried adding the following lines to both `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bash.bashrc`. I'm not sure I understand the difference between the two files but I really think either one should work on an interactive shell, right?

```
export HISTCONTROL=erasedups:ignorespace
export HISTSIZE=5000
shopt -s histappend
```

For some reason this won't work though. I have added the lines to the bottom, logged out, logged back in, and typed `echo $HISTSIZE` and I get "`1000`"?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the default ubuntu `~/.bashrc` sets `HISTSIZE` to `1000`. `~/.bashrc` has precedence over `/etc/bash.bashrc`. check your `~/.bashrc`, and those of all other users too.

Comment: I originally set it in `~/.bashrc` for my user, but then decided I wanted to change it for all users. I removed it from `~/.bashrc` but am still not having much luck getting it to load globally.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks @lesmana, you are correct. I have added the block of code to `/etc/bash.bashrc` and made sure it was not in any of the users profiles. That worked well. I also realized that I should set it in `/etc/bash.bashrc` and not `/etc/profile` because the first one is for `bash` (which `history` is pertinent to) and the second one is for Bourne shell (sh(1)) and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ).