# Changing ubuntu 18 History size

Tags: bash, bashrc, history

Im trying to change ( Globally) the 
HISTSIZE & HISTFILESIZE 
I've tried to add the values into /etc/bash.bashrc

and its not working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `grep HIST /etc/skel/.bashrc` It is copied from there to ~/.bashrc when a user is created.

Comment: Possible solution : https://askubuntu.com/questions/86339/how-can-i-set-histsize-for-all-users

Comment: @Cyrus changing this file actaully works for new users, but i want this changes to take affect on current users also... any suggetions?